# Socket.io emit does not emit anything to the clients

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have written a simple function like this in Node.js

```
const socketIo = require("socket.io")
const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
    },
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit("hello", "world");
});
```

But still nothing is being received when I have established connection on postman[image]

I have also tried sending a message and maintaining 2 parallel connection, still no luck.

Comment: Closing this post, as apparently I was not listening to events in Postman.